# Joins Using AS in :select with ActiveRecord

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to do this

```
Version.find(:all, :joins=>"JOIN editions ON versions.edition_id=editions.id JOIN products ON editions.product_id=products.id", :select=>"products.name, versions.name AS what")
```

but ActiveRecord is not respecting the AS keyword... any ideas?

**Edit:** Since both fields are called "name" they are colliding, so I only get the last one in the list.

Comment: Just ran something very similar that worked for me. Could you describe the problem more? Is ActiveRecord loading products.name into versions.name? Does versions.first.what not contain the value in versions.name?

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for your comment. My misunderstanding was with IRB (or the Rails console, or both)... things.first.what did indeed contain what I needed. However, thing.first did not show it in the Console..... still learning. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the query:

Product has_many editions (just specifying the relationship here)

Edition has_many versions

```
foo = Version.find(:all, :joins=>"JOIN editions ON versions.edition_id=editions.id JOIN products ON editions.product_id=products.id", :select=>"products.name, versions.name AS what")
puts foo.inspect
```

> This should give you a value:
>
> `[#<Version name: "foobar1">, #<Version name: "foobar2">]`

```
foo[0].what # Will print the value of 'what' returned by the query
```

When I wrote a similar query a similar hierarchy it gave me perfect results. Would you like to share the stack trace if you are getting an error?

EDIT: foo[0].attributes will print {"name" => "foobar1", "what" => ""}
Sorry for the typo here. I had meant to say attributes.

Comment: Yes! I thought that the console would just spit out all the values, but in fact it doesn't.